# Elevate privileges on python to set the date on windows

Tags: python

I have a simple python function to set the date of my computer. But in order to do that i need to elevate my privileges, here is the code I used :

```
def setWinDateHour(date):

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)
    win32api.SetSystemTime(date.year, date.month, now.weekday(), date.day, now.hour, now.minute, now.second,
                              int(now.microsecond / 1000))
```

The system asks me if I want to run the program as an admin, I click on "yes" but i still get the error about no sufficient privileges.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the os library to run terminal commands and change the date like so:

```
os.system(f'date {date.month}-{date.day}-{date.year}')
os.system(f'time {now.hour}:{now.minute}:{now.second}.{str(int(now.microsecond / 1000))}')
```

Remember to import the library at the beginning of the file:

```
import os
```

On Windows you can also do this:
Get date:

```
os.system("date")
```

Get time:

```
os.system("time")
```

Set date:

```
os.system("date mm-dd-yyyy")
```

Set time:

```
os.system("time hh:mm:ss.ms")
```

And to run VSCode as administrator on the Windows desktop, right-click on the Visual Studio shortcut and then select Properties. Select the Advanced button and then select the Run as administrator check box. Select OK, and then select OK again.

Comment: thanks but my problem is that i'm not allowed to launch the program as administrator (for an assignment)

Comment: Could you show me the error?

Comment: (1314, 'SetSystemTime', 'Le client ne dispose pas d’un privilège nécessaire.')

Translation : The client does not have a necessary privilege.

Comment: If you are using the Windows terminal try to open it as administrator, pressing right click and open as administrator

Comment: I'm using pycharm, but as I said, it's an assignment and i'm not allowed to launch the program as an administrator..

Comment: That library requires the use of administrator if I'm not wrong, try the method that I have described in my answer. Or are you forced to use that library?

Comment: I got pretty much the same error with your method: Choice : Le client ne dispose pas d'un privil�ge n�cessaire."
Translation: the client doesn't have the necessary privileges"

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to do it without being an administrator